# "Rotation Quaternions must be unit length" using rigidbody.MoveRotation in unity

Tags: unity, quaternion, rigidbody

I'm making a game that involves throwing things with catapults. The cup of a catapult needs to use `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` to let a ball respond to being thrown in the physics engine. I use the following code for my update function(just as a test):

```cs
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (transform.rotation.z > -95.4)
            {
                Quaternion targetRotation= new Quaternion(0f,0f,(float)(transform.rotation.z-5*Time.deltaTime),0f);
                targetRotation=rigidbody.rotation;//rigidbody is a Rigidbody object
                targetRotation.z -= 5;
                rigidbody.MoveRotation(targetRotation);
            }
        }
    }
```

This has been giving me the error `Rotation quaternions must be unit length`. I can't find a reference to that in the unity API, and the one solution I found online was to use the Quaternion's `normalize` attribute. However, when I did this, the throwing arm rotated 180° almost instantly, and then the same error got thrown a bunch of times. How do I prevent this error from happening, and how do I slow down the rotation?(changing the values doesn't seem to help). And yes, interpolation is on in the rigidbody component. Let me know if you need more info, thanks!

Comment: the only idea I have now is that I can use normalize and just call moverotation less often.

Comment: Quaternions use complex numbers (with real+imaginary parts) to represent a 3D rotation in 4D space. `w` is the real component, `xyz` are imaginary. All of which to say... You're not setting angles when you set raw quaternion values. Use the helper methods on the quaternion class to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not meaningful to manipulate individual components of a quaternion the way you're doing. They're not Euler angles. They're points on a 4-dimensional unit sphere where three of the dimensions are imaginary numbers. So, better to stick to the methods of the `Quaternion` class for manipulating them.

It looks like what you want is something more like this:

```
// Physics interactions should be done in FixedUpdate for framerate independence.
void FixedUpdate() 
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && transform.localRotation.z > -95.4)
    {
        // Apply the speed of rotation directly, along the desired rotation axis.
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = transform.forward * -rotationSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code didn't work. Changing the angular velocity didn't move the arm of the catapult whatsoever. How do I get it to actually move?

Comment: Sorry if that sounded aggressive it wasn't meant that way

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to ask "How do I convert this catapult to work with physics" showing us the details of how your assets are set up in the hierarchy. We'll need a minimal complete verifiable example so we can be sure proposed solutions work for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning in the Unity [documentation about Quaternion class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html):

> Don't modify this directly unless you know quaternions inside out.

I don't fully understand [the math behind quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) either. But that's no problem when using Unity, because it provides so many useful convenience methods for working with quaternions that you will never encounter a situation where you really need to. You can be a perfectly competent Unity developer when you just accept that the inner workings of quaternions are black magic. Just see them as magic black boxes which encode a rotation around an arbitrary axis in 3d space by a certain angle and move on with your life.

- When your catapult arm is a rigidbody, and the projectile it is supposed to launch is also a rigidbody, then you could leave the whole catapult mechanics to the Unity physics engine. Just cause the catapult arm to rotate by applying a torque with [Rigidbody.AddTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html).
- When you prefer to handle the projectile launching physics yourself and make the catapult arm movement entirely cosmetic, then you can rotate it with [Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html). This method only needs three pieces of information:

  - The current roation, which you can get through `transform.rotation`
  - The desired final rotation, which you do not need to state in the `x, y, z, w` form but can generate through [Quaternion.Euler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) or set in the inspector.
  - Number of degree you want to turn on this frame. Which you usually calculate by taking a constant angular velocity in degree per second and multiplying it by `Time.deltaTime`.
- Or don't hardcode the movement of the arm at all, and do it with the [animation system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html). The animation system is not just for character models. It can animate any public inspector property, including the rotation of a transform.

Comment: I tried adding a torque vector with AddTorque, and it didn't move the arm at all. I'm not sure if my vector( it was 0,0,1) was wrong, but do I also need to modify the angular velocity or hardcode the rotation in conjunction with AddTorque?

Comment: @NathanWolf You might want to try experimenting with rigidbodies and forces in a simpler scene first in order to make sure there isn't anything in your scene which could break stuff. It will then get a lot easier for you to understand what could be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Rigidbody methods in `Update` method as much as you can do. I have met similar issues several times. The best you can do is to use Rigidbody related methods in `FixedUpdate` method. Especially if they depend on `deltaTime - fixedDeltaTime`, I highly recommend you to use Rigidbody in `FixedUpdate`. Even if you try to use `Time.deltaTime` in `FixedUpdate` method Unity will know and convert it to `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

Comment: This is not wrong, but unrelated to the actual problem in this question.

Comment: Actually the problem is inital quaternion value. Yesterday, i ran into the same problem and interestingly i solved it changing Start method to Awake method.  I guess sometimes execution order of scripts leads this problem. ^^

Comment: You may want to mention that in the answer, then.